# How to generate JRE fontconfig files on Arch ARM?

Tags: archlinux, java, arm

I'm trying to make a small Java application with UI and run it on Arch Linux ARM, but every time I try rendering a text, it crashes with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1264)
        at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:219)
        at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
        at sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:774)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:431)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:376)
        at sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
```

After some debugging I noticed the FontManager is looking for the file `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/fontconfig.properties`, which is not present on my system despite having installed both `libfontconfig`:

```
[root@raspberry-pawel jezor]# pacman -Q | grep font
cantarell-fonts 1:0.100-1
fontconfig 2.12.6+5+g665584a-1
fontsproto 2.1.3-2
libfontenc 1.1.3-1
libxfont2 2.0.3-1
xorg-font-util 1.3.1-1
xorg-font-utils 7.6-4
xorg-fonts-100dpi 1.0.3-3
xorg-fonts-75dpi 1.0.3-3
xorg-fonts-alias 1.0.3-1
xorg-fonts-encodings 1.0.4-4
xorg-mkfontdir 1.0.7-8
xorg-mkfontscale 1.1.2-1
```

and non-headless `JRE`:

```
[root@raspberry-pawel jezor]# pacman -Q | grep jre
jre8-openjdk 8.u111-1
jre8-openjdk-headless 8.u111-1
```

Why this file could be missing? What is usually generating it (on my laptop it contains a comment "Java generated do not touch")? How can I generate it myself?